# ServiceStack Razor Intellisense not working in SelfHost

Tags: razor, servicestack, self-hosting

I have ServiceStack.Razor referenced.

Following razor file works great:

```
@model ServiceStack.Host.Operation

@Model.Name
```

but IntelliSense (and R# code analysis) shows error: **"Cannot resolve symbol 'model'"**

Referencing Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc makes Intellisense work, but Razor pages are not compiled.
This is because ServiceStack.Razor contains System.Web.Razor assembly version 3.0.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc requires a 3.2.3, one is overwritten by other and assembly load exceptions occur.

Tried to follow this answer:
[ServiceStack turn on Razor intellisense support without MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721108/servicestack-turn-on-razor-intellisense-support-without-mvc?rq=1)

and add Web.config but this gives me different error:
**"Cannot access private field 'model' here"**

How to make Intellisense work without breaking application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately VS.NET 2015 designer doesn't properly support editing Razor pages in Self-Host (i.e. non ASP.NET Projects) so you wont be able to get rid of all the designer errors, although you can minimize the issues by first adding a `Web.config` with the Razor configuration, here's a [Web.config template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS/blob/master/src/ServiceStackVS/ProjectTemplates/RazorSelfHost/RazorSelfHost/Web.config) you can use, you'll need to replace `$safeprojectname$` with the namespace of your project. The `Web.config` have no effect to the behavior of non Web projects, it's just use to provide hints to VS.NET intellisense which is coupled to ASP.NET Web projects.

Instead of `@model` you'll want to use the more explicit:

```
@inherits ViewPage<ServiceStack.Host.Operation>
```

These both do the same thing, but the designer is happier with the explicit `@inherits`.